# Showing a relationship between two functions.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Suppose $X$ is a discrete random variable which can take values $x_1,x_2,\ldots,$ with $0\le x_1<x_2<\ldots$. Suppose $0\le f(x)\le 1$ and $0\le g(x) \le \infty$ be a function of $x$.

If $g(x_j)=1-\frac{f(x_{j+1})}{f(x_j)}\quad j=1,2,\ldots,$ then how can I show that $f(x)=\prod_{j:x_j<x}[1-g(x_j)]$?

#### My Attempt:

$$g(x_j)=1-\frac{f(x_{j+1})}{f(x_j)}\quad j=1,2,\ldots,$$
$$\Rightarrow \frac{f(x_{j+1})}{f(x_j)}=1-g(x_j)$$
$$\Rightarrow f(x_j)=\frac{1}{1-g(x_j)}f(x_{j+1})$$
$$\Rightarrow f(x_j)=\frac{1}{1-g(x_j)}\frac{1}{1-g(x_{j+1})}f(x_{j+2})$$
???

Comment: Please correct the expression you want to prove in the question above. for one, $t_j$ should change to $x_j$ and $f(x)$ should I think be $f(x_{j+1})$ or something like that.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг Thanks. I've edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{f(x_{j+1})}{f(x_j)}=1-g(x_j)$$ can be written as
$$\frac{f(x_{j})}{f(x_{j-1})}=1-g(x_{j-1})$$
Now you continue the same way as you did before:
$$f(x_{j})=(1-g(x_{j-1}))f(x_{j-1})=(1-g(x_{j-1}))(1-g(x_{j-2}))f(x_{j-2})=...$$

Comment: At a point, doesn't it comes $f(x_{j})=(1-g(x_{j-1}))(1-g(x_{j-2}))...(1-g(x_{j-j}))f(x_{j-j})$?

Comment: If so, then the implicit assumptions are $f(x_0)=1$ and $g(x_0)=0$.

Comment: Correct. It is not stated in the problem. Note that $f(x)$ must be decreasing, otherwise $g(x)$ will have negative values. Since $f(x)\le1$, if it attains the value of $1$ anywhere it must be at $x_0$

Comment: But why  the subscript of the product sign of the equation $f(x)=\prod_{j:x_j<x}[1-g(x_j)]$ doesn't have a equal sign? That is, it is not $f(x)=\prod_{j:x_j\mathbf \le x}[1-g(x_j)]$?

Comment: Just look at the first term in the expansion. You have $x_{j-1}$ since $x_j\gt x_{j-1}$ you have strict "less then $x$"